# What happened in the Narrows during and after the release of the Fear toxin?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, batman-begins

In *Batman Begins*, Scarecrow releases the Fear toxin into the Narrows.  We see a bit of chaos, but we don't find out what happened in full.  It seems like a **lot** of people must have been killed.  Is there more information about the events off screen and after the movie ended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the film's [official novelisation](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Begins_(Book)). There was a riot in the Narrows and several hundred people were killed. After the cure was found, the area returned to a semblance of normality:

> *In the week since the monorail incident and the massive disruption of the city’s infrastructure, Gordon and his cops had restored order and
>   the public works guys had completed the most necessary repairs to the
>   water system. Pretty soon, everyone who wanted one would have an
>   injection of the serum Rachel Dawes had given him and the nutso stuff
>   Crane and Rā’s al Ghūl had put into the air wouldn’t ever again be a
>   threat. Every drug lab in the state was helping turn out batches of
>   the serum and most of the severely damaged citizens had already been
>   injected and were returning to their sane selves. Those who had been
>   under the influence of Crane’s hallucinogen the longest would need
>   years of therapy, but there were only small numbers of those. **There
>   were also a couple of hundred people dead, but nothing could be done
>   about them except to mourn. Even the Narrows area was returning to
>   normal, or at least as “normal” as the Narrows ever got.** Gordon had
>   never exactly been a Mr. Sunshine, but he felt cautiously optimistic.
>   Maybe things were looking up.*